# 2 way binding is not working properly in vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I have defined a vuejs component this way:

```
<template>
    <form @submit.prevent="submit">
        <textarea id="content" cols="30" rows="10" v-model="content">{{ content }}</textarea>

        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-success" type="submit" @click="send()">
            Send content
        </button>
    </form>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                content: '// Initial content'
            }
        },
        methods: {
            send() {
                console.log('Content', this.content);
            },
            submit() {
                return false;
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            console.log('Template init ', this.content);
        }
    }
</script>
```

When I click on send, the send method outputs the content of the textarea as expected. But when I change the content of the textarea with jquery:

`$('#content').val(content);`

and hit send, it doesn't update content in the template. "Send" outputs the old value.

can somebody please explain to me what's wrong here?

Comment: Not entirely sure, but I think it's not recommended to use jQuery alongside Vue, maybe Vue can't keep track of changes made with jQuery o something like that

Comment: I think I don't have a choice at this point. It's a workaround that i come up with in order to copy the content of another block generated by a a plugin, which I can't access from vuejs.

Comment: Maybe use a computed property to watch the other value instead?

Comment: @MattiPrice I don't think I get your point.

Comment: like change `content` to be a computed property with a value of whatever you are using jquery to pull a value for.

Comment: @arakibi https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#ad maybe here you can find how to make it work

Comment: I don't think this would work because the textarea keeps changing its value.

Answer (score 1):

`v-model` is listening for an input event to trigger changing the value of its bound variable.

From the [vue.js documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html):

> v-model internally uses different properties and emits different
> events for different input elements:
>
> - text and textarea elements use value property and input event;
> - checkboxes and radiobuttons use checked property and change event;
> - select fields use value as a prop and change as an event.

Using the JQuery val() method to select the element and change the value does not trigger an event that `v-model` is listening for, so the value of your bound variable does not change/update.

If you absolutely have to use JQuery to change the content, you could manually trigger an event that might also trigger the `v-model` binding to update:

`$('#content').val(content).trigger('input');`